# Rarely getting ClientException and ZuulException in spring boot, eureka, zuul, ribbon framework

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have configured my project architecture using Spring Boot, Eureka, Zuul, Ribbon frameworks.
Its working fine but sometimes (rarely) getting the following exceptions:

1. Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: **service1**
2. Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: **service1** timed-out and no fallback available.

Below are my services configurations: 
Have a look and please let me know if I missed anything which causing the issues for above exceptions.

**eureka service application.properties:**

```
server.port=8070
spring.application.name=eureka_service
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8070/eureka/
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

**zuul service application.properties:**

```
server.port=8071
spring.application.name=zuul_service
zuul.prefix=/api
zuul.routes.service1.path=/service1/**
zuul.routes.service1.service-id=service1
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8070/eureka/
ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
```

**service1 application.properties:**

```
server.port=8072
spring.application.name=service1
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8070/eureka/
ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
```

Please let me know if I need to add any other configuration to resolve ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are these exceptions on start up? 

It can take 120 seconds, if you are unlucky, for the meta data to be shared for discovery between services. 

Additionally Hystrix has a default 1 second timeout with a threadpool of 10, you can easily DOS yourself if you keep Hystrix defaults.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe These exceptions NOT on startup. I am getting when I tried to access the service1 API via Zuul.

http://localhost:8071/api/security1/user/*****

How can I resolve these exceptions ?

Comment: I should clarify, how quickly after the applications come up are you trying to hit the APIs?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I tried to hit the APIs after all services are UP and running and after ensuring all services registered successfully on Eureka server.  I am getting these exceptions, sometimes for API 1st hit after server started, sometimes after several hits. I am not getting what is the issue !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase the Ribbon timeout by setting for example:

```
ribbon.ReadTimeout=10000
```

If above code doesn't work you can try by disabling the timeout:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
```

Comment: this isn't solely related to hystrix either.